# mysql optimizer confusion explain plan

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, trace, explain

I am hoping someone can help decipher an explain plan and information in the optimizer trace.

**I have the following query:**

```
select doc_id,
       group_concat(distinct concat(a.event_time, id mod 10) order by id) as times,
       count(distinct id) as count_of_items   
        FROM doc_audit  a,
             rwfd1213310051e2821b404f29bc453ce7386f764e b 
        WHERE b.rptid = a.doc_id 
          AND  a.property = 'status'  
        group by 1;
```

**And get this execution plan.**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1                                              
  select_type: SIMPLE                                         
        table: b                                              
   partitions: NULL                                           
         type: index                                          
possible_keys: idx_tmp_rptid                                  
          key: idx_tmp_rptid                                  
      key_len: 8                                              
          ref: NULL                                           
         rows: 7153                                           
     filtered: 100.00                                         
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref                                            
possible_keys: DOC_ID_PROPERTY_IDX,event_time,event_time2
          key: DOC_ID_PROPERTY_IDX
      key_len: 776
          ref: database.b.rptid,const
         rows: 2
     filtered: 43.75
        Extra: Using where
```

My limited understanding is the order in the explain plan is the order the plan is executed.  If this is the case I don't understand where the "**Using filsort**" comes from on table b?  If I enable the optimzer profile trace it suggests the filsort is related to table a.  I reached this conclusion because doc_id is in table a.  Furthermore I believe filsort simply means "Sort"? doc_id is indexed so I don't understand why it needs sorting further.

```
        "filesort_information": [                        
          {                                              
            "direction": "asc",                          
            "table": "intermediate_tmp_table",           
            "field": "**doc_id**"                            
          }                                              
        ],                                               
        "filesort_priority_queue_optimization": {        
          "usable": false,                               
          "cause": "not applicable (no LIMIT)"           
        },                                               
        "filesort_execution": [                          
        ],                                               
        "filesort_summary": {                            
          "rows": 17620,                                 
          "examined_rows": 17620,                        
          "number_of_tmp_files": 2,                      
          "sort_buffer_size": 262128,                    
          "sort_mode": "<sort_key, rowid>"
```

I would really appreciate any help on this.  Apologies if my understanding is way off.

**doc_audit**

```
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY DOC_ID_PROPERTY_IDX (doc_id,property), 
    KEY event (instance_id,event,event_time), 
    KEY event_time (doc_id,event,event_time), 
    KEY event_user (instance_id,user_id,event,event_time), 
    KEY event_time2 (event_time,doc_id,event), 
    KEY user (user_id,event_time,instance_id), 
    KEY event_time_user_event (event_time,user_id,event(80))
```

Adding the table defs:

```
CREATE TABLE doc_audit (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  doc_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  event varchar(255) ,
  event_time datetime NOT NULL,
  instance_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  major_version int(11) NOT NULL,
  minor_version int(11) NOT NULL,
  new_value varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  old_value varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  property varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  signature_meaning varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  task_name varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  version int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_name varchar(255)  DEFAULT NULL,
  user_on_behalf_of bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  xml longtext,
  user_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_display_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  document_number varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  property_public_key varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  property_label varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  old_value_public_key varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  old_value_label varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  new_value_public_key varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  new_value_label varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_label varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  task_label varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  precalculated bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY DOC_ID_PROPERTY_IDX (doc_id,property),
  KEY event (instance_id,event,event_time),
  KEY event_time (doc_id,event,event_time),
  KEY event_user (instance_id,user_id,event,event_time),
  KEY event_time2 (event_time,doc_id,event),
  KEY user (user_id,event_time,instance_id),
  KEY event_time_user_event (event_time,user_id,event(80))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1209095 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and..

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rwfd1213310051e2821b404f29bc453ce7386f764e (
  wfrptid bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  workflow_status__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_id__v bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  task_capacity_key__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_process_version__v bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_name__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_initiator_name__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  task_delegate__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_completionDate__v datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_initiator__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_cancelationDate__v datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_document_id__v bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  task_verdict_key__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_lifecycle__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  task_assignee_name__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  task_meta_data_id__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  task_completionDate__v datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  workflow_startDate__v datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  task_iteration_count__v bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  rptid bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  major_version_number__v bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  minor_version_number__v bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  study__v varchar(1500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  document_number__v varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  status__v varchar(1500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  name__v varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  days_in_qc__c bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  durationInValue15f07c5893cf4ba98a3441aab045c460
         varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  0PERIOD int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY idx_tmp_rptid (rptid)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the indexes you have on your tables.

Comment: Thanks Andy, the indexes for doc_audit  are as follows: PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `DOC_ID_PROPERTY_IDX` (`doc_id`,`property`),
KEY `event` (`instance_id`,`event`,`event_time`),
KEY `event_time` (`doc_id`,`event`,`event_time`),
KEY `event_user` (`instance_id`,`user_id`,`event`,`event_time`),
KEY `event_time2` (`event_time`,`doc_id`,`event`),
KEY `user` (`user_id`,`event_time`,`instance_id`),
KEY `event_time_user_event` (`event_time`,`user_id`,`event`(80)).  The temp table has the following index: idx_tmp_rptid(rptid)

Comment: `b` seems to be unused; get rid of it.  (Or are you checking for the existence of a row in `b`?  Or maybe there can be multiple rows in `b`, in which case you get multiple ids in the group_concat?

Answer (score 1):

Two exceptions to the order of tables in `EXPLAIN`:

- Subqueries tend to be at the end of the `EXPLAIN`.
- `Using temporary` and `Using filesort` tend to be on the first line of the `EXPLAIN`, giving you no clue of when they are actually used.  Also, there may be more than one sort, again without a clue.

The `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` is better at saying what part needed the sort.  Multiple filesorts show up clearly.

"filesort" is a generic term.  It might involve disk (slowest), it might be a 'quicksort' in RAM, or it might be "filesort_priority_queue_optimization" (handy with `LIMIT`).  There may be other options.

(Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

`event(80)` -- Index prefixes are rarely useful.  Was this a `TEXT` column?

The optimal index for this query for `a` is

```
INDEX(property, doc_id, event_time, id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rick.  I tried adding the index you suggested.  The optimzer still chose DOC_ID_PROPERTY_IDX (doc_id,property).  I added the table defs above.  Not sure why the formatting is wrecked.